# Convox multiline environment variables

Tags: environment, convox

How can I add multiline env variable to convox? I’ve tried to add it via console.convox.com, and only first line is added, other lines are being truncated. Tried via `convox env set VAR $VAR`, and it’s being set as a single line. Tried with `convox env set VAR "$VAR"` and got an error `bad flag syntax: -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----.`. Tried HEREDOC, got same error.

Any ideas how to get this thing working?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use a multiline environment variable with Convox is to encode it with something like base64. You can then decode it in your application before use.